# Different ways of splitting numbers into lists and when to use them?

Tags: python, string, list

What is the difference and pro/cons of using these 3 methods when splitting numbers into lists:

`list(number)`

or

`[int(x) for x in str(number)]`

or

`number.split()`

And what exactly does everything in`[int(x) for x in str(number)]` do?

I know they all split the string, but I'm not sure when to use for which situations.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `number`? Is it actually a number, or a string? If it's a number, `list(number)` and `number.split()` would both throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one you want to use depends on what you're trying to do with the string you have (assuming "number" is actually a string object).

`list(myString)` will create a list containing each character of the string separately, so `"12345"` becomes `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`. Notice that each element of the list is still a string, so it will be treated like text, even though the text itself is a number.

`[int(x) for x in number]` (using `str()` on a string doesn't do anything) is slightly different. In this case, you would get a list containing each character of the string converted into the actual number that the digit represents. So, `"12345"` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. In this case, if any character in the string isn't a digit, it would throw an exception.

`number.split()` is the simplest, it just splits the string into a list at each whitespace, so `"12345"` just becomes `["12345"]`, but `"123 456"` would become `["123", "456"]`. This situation is similar to the first case, in that each element in the list is still a string and will be treated like text, not a number.

For most situations, you would probably want to use a combination of these (like `[int(x) for x in number.split()]`) to parse each number in the string into an actual number separately, instead of converting the characters in the string into number individually.

Answer (score 1):

They are all a bit different.

Example 1 puts all your number in a list but as you can notice from the quotation marks they are of type string:

```
numbers = '12345'
print(list(numbers))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Example 2 is called list comprehension and it's quicker than a for loop while providing similar flexibility. The int(x) part changes it from string to integer type.

```
new_list = [int(x) for x in numbers]
print(new_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
for x in '12345':
    new_list.append(int(x))
print(new_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Example 3 needs some kind of delimiter. Like a space:

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5'
print(numbers.split(' '))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Or a comma:

```
numbers = '1,2,3,4,5'
print(numbers.split(','))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Notice how example 1 and 3 don't change the value type to integer like example two does.